# Can I download an Entities List from my bot using LUIS?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I manually inputted thousands of data points into my LUIS bot for an Entities List but I may have to start over with a new bot. Is there any way to preserve my Entities List that I made?

Comment: You can [export your Luis application](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de481)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the luis.ai page, once logged you can see your applications at https://www.luis.ai/applications.

Right from there, you can export your application using the **{}** button.
[image]

Then, you can just click the **Import App** button (in that account or in another one) to import it back.

Answer (score 0):

As stuartd said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592264/can-i-download-an-entities-list-from-my-bot-using-luis#comment76172237_44592264), you can export the entire LUIS model via the Authoring API. To do this you'll use the *v2.0* API; here you can [export by App ID and version ID](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40).

You can also find instructions on acquiring *only* your list entity via the Authoring API [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c15).

Chances are though, you'll probably want to follow Ezequiel's instructions and just download your LUIS model via the portal.