# How do I get key/value from entity list in LUIS [botframework]

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to have my bot breakdown the definition of various acronyms. I have all of them added into an entities list and the synonyms are the values which I would like to display. I would like to know how to handle this JSON data and call the correct information so that in this case the acronym WWW will result in "world wide web"

[image: For example I want the definition of WWW which should be world wide web.]

[image]

I would like to receive the canonical form and output the synonym "world wide web". I just don't understand how to do this in node.js. Can someone please clarify in what object I can find the synonyms to a searched entity from this list.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question. Do you want to know how to use LUIS in a BotFramework/Node.js based bot?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding where the object I am looking for is. I can see from the result that it is identifying my entity list "Industry Acronyms" but how can I get the paired value to "WWW"

Comment: @EzequielJadib I added another screenshot from LUIS.ai to try and make it more clear what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need the synonyms, you can just export your [LUIS model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44594144/7794490) and extract the `"closedLists"` kvp from there. Then map that to an object and access that object from your code.

However... I think you might be setting up your list entity incorrectly, if I understand you correctly. Or conceptually you may be thinking of your list entity in a different sense.

The canonical form is the value you **want** your code to handle. Say I want to set up a list entity for New York, New York. We'll say `"New York, New York"` is the canonical form. We'll gather up synonyms for New York, New York, because honestly, that's a pain to constantly type/write out or say aloud.

Our canonical form: `"New York, New York"`
Our synonyms are: `"New York City", "NYC", "The Big Apple", "NY, NY"`

### | Canonical Form | Synonyms |

| **"New York, New York"** | ***"New York City", "NYC", "The Big Apple", "NY, NY"*** |

I'm submitting the recognized entity to a database, I don't want to have an entry with `"New York City"`, two entries with `"NYC"` and a hundred entries with `"New York, New York"`. Handling that would be a nightmare, and least of all extremely inefficient.

When I submit the data to the database, I'm ignoring their actual utterance and using the canonical form because through the list entity I've standardized user input.

That all said, inside of the code you can do the following for handling list entities.

Here's a snippet on extracting the canonical form `"WWW"` from the `"Industry Acronyms"`-recognized entity.

```
var yourEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity('Industry Arconyms', results.response);

var canonicalForm;
var recognizedSynonym;


yourEntity.resolution.values.forEach(function (canonical_form) {
    if (canonical_form == "WWW") {
        recognizedSynonym = yourEntity.entity;
    }
})
```

But if you want to receive every canonical form in the entity, you would do something like this:

```
var canonicalForms = [];

yourEntity.resolution.values.forEach(function (canonical_form) {
        canonicalForms.push(canonical_form);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly... you want access to the synonyms, but they aren't being sent in the JSON?

If this is the case you could consider making a dictionary `public Dictionary<string,List<string>>` if you have multiple synonyms or `public Dictionary<string,string>` if there is just one per acronym.  Then you can use the value from entity to look up the synonyms in your code.

Comment: This might work but I have thousands of Acronyms and they are all in an entity list. There must be a better way to access that information.

Comment: I feel your pain, but I do not see a way to get synonyms in the JSON

Comment: you also have the ability to download your LUIS model and therefore the ability to copy/paste or write code to read/use the parts of the model you need.